# A lot of core JavaScript files not being included

Tags: 7, javascript

For some reason a bunch of core JS files are not being loaded. I've had to manually add them in with a module `hook_js_alter` function like so:

```
function MYMODULE_js_alter(&$js) {
    drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.js', array('group' => JS_LIBRARY, 'weight' => -100, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'scope' => 'header'));
    drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.once.js', array('group' => JS_LIBRARY, 'weight' => -99, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'scope' => 'header'));
    drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.cookie.js', array('group' => JS_LIBRARY, 'weight' => -98, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'scope' => 'header'));
    drupal_add_js('misc/form.js', array('weight' => 19, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'scope' => 'header'));
    drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js', array('weight' => 20, 'every_page' => TRUE, 'scope' => 'header'));
}
```

The only core JS file loading by itself is `drupal.js`, and a bunch of module scripts. Other than that I had to include the 5 above myself, otherwise various parts of the public site and admin areas were not working.

This works, but it feels really sketchy. And previously I had only included the first 3, until I noticed more admin form stuff breaking. So I hate to think that there may be MORE scripts that I will only discover missing through trial and error.

Any ideas why they are not being included??

**UPDATE**

I've narrowed it down, there are two custom modules which are breaking it. One of them is much simpler than the other so I'll just try to figure that one out first. This line of code, inside the .module file, and not within any function, is causing the issue ($form_js is a string containing JavaScript)

```
drupal_add_js($form_js, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
```

Comment: I noticed that on another admin import page, `progress.js` and `batch.js` were not being included. -_- What is going on?!

Comment: Any errors on the browser's log or drupal recent log? It happend after installing a new module or code modificaton?

Comment: @Rotem no errors in the recent log. There *were* errors in the JS console because the files were not being included, jQuery was not defined, etc. After I manually added the JS files in, no console errors either

Comment: @Rotem unfortunately I am coming into this project after someone else has built most of it, so I couldn't say when or what module may have caused it. Maybe my best bet is to disable modules one at a time :/

Comment: If you have devel installed, try to use `dpm($js);` on the begining of your implementation of `hook_js_alter()` and see if the files exists in that array.

Comment: @Rotem no, they are not present in the array

Comment: @Rotem see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that using `drupal_add_js` outside of a `hook_js_alter` function in another file was causing the issue.

```
drupal_add_js($form_js, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));
```

Now that it is within the function, it's working fine.

I don't see anything in the documentation saying that this is required -> also, `drupal_add_css` works fine outside of a function. I'm not altering any existing JS files, only adding new ones.

So while I don't understand **why** this is an issue, this is the solution